# Multiple Outer Joins vs. Single Join with Multiple OR Conditions in ON

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

Which of the following is preferable? These queries give the same results (correct me if I'm wrong). The first takes 75-80ms while the second takes 35-40ms in my tests. Should the first approach be avoided?

The first approach is with multiple Outer Joins. The second is with a single Join with multiple OR conditions.

I am selecting `Agreements` where one of 3 columns (`REQUESTER_ID`, `APPROVING_OFFICIAL_ID`, `SECOND_LEVEL_AO_ID`) matches `NED_PERSON_T.ID` for a provided `NED_PERSON_T.uniqueidentifier` and `AGREEMENT_T.id`. Thanks

**1.**

```
 SELECT agreement_t.id 
FROM   agreement_t 
JOIN   ned_person_t AS ned_person_t_1
ON     agreement_t.requester_id = ned_person_t_1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN   ned_person_t AS ned_person_t_2
ON     agreement_t.approving_official_id = ned_person_t_2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN   ned_person_t AS ned_person_t_3
ON     agreement_t.second_approving_official_id = ned_person_t_3.id
WHERE  (
              ned_person_t_1.uniqueidentifier = '123'
       OR     ned_person_t_2.uniqueidentifier = '123'
       OR     ned_person_t_3.uniqueidentifier = '123' )
AND    agreement_t.id = 45 
LIMIT 1
```

**2.**

```
 SELECT agreement_t.id 
FROM   agreement_t
JOIN   ned_person_t
ON     
   (agreement_t.requester_id = ned_person_t.id
     OR     agreement_t.approving_official_id = ned_person_t.id
     OR     agreement_t.second_approving_official_id = ned_person_t.id
   )
WHERE  ned_person_t.uniqueidentifier = '123'
AND    agreement_t.id = 45 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Those queries do not necessarily give the same result.

Comment: In what example do they not give the same result? I don't need specific code, just a general pointer.

Comment: The first one yields no rows if `agreement_t.requester_id = ned_person_t_1.id` cannot be satisfied even if one of the other conditions can be satisfied, while the second one will give a row as long as one of the other conditions can be satisfied.

Comment: OK, and what if **all 3** were Outer Joins, and not just the last 2? (Thanks for your help, btw.)

Comment: Please lead with the Postgres version in use for any performance question. Then `CREATE TABLE` statements showing data types and constraints. Applicable indexes, row counts, and data distribution for relevant columns. Detailed instructions here: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3299/3684 Applying the most selective filters early is key to performance. Also, explain your `LIMIT 1`, and which filters can vary and how.

Answer (score 3):

With 3x `LEFT JOIN`, the first query is equivalent. And typically slower due to the  multiple joins.
Your query **1.** with less noise:

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM   agreement_t a
LEFT   JOIN ned_person_t n1 ON n1.id = a.requester_id
LEFT   JOIN ned_person_t n2 ON n2.id = a.approving_official_id
LEFT   JOIN ned_person_t n3 ON n3.id = a.second_approving_official_id
WHERE  a.id = 45 
AND   (n1.uniqueidentifier = '123'
    OR n2.uniqueidentifier = '123'
    OR n3.uniqueidentifier = '123')
LIMIT  1;
```

Your query **2.**:

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM   agreement_t a
JOIN   ned_person_t n ON n.id IN (a.requester_id, a.approving_official_id, a.second_approving_official_id)
WHERE  a.id = 45 
AND    n.uniqueidentifier = '123'
LIMIT  1;
```

Without `LIMIT 1`, the queries may or may not be equivalent. Multiple `LEFT JOIN`s can multiply rows if `ned_person_t.id` is not defined `UNIQUE`. Depends on undisclosed information.

Comment: I would write the query with a exists subquery and not a join.

Comment: Result is deterministic in the case of LIMIT 1, this is due to the very limited select clause. - Any row returned will contain the single value 45.

Comment: @Taemyr: True, with `WHERE  a.id = 45` it's deterministic after all. That slipped my attention. And yes, `EXISTS` would lend itself naturally to this query. (It will probably result in the same query plan as the second query.)